# How to override admin js file in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

How to override vendor/magento/module-product-video/view/adminhtml/web/js/get-video-information.js file. I need to remove video URL validation from product page in Magento 2 admin.

Comment: you need to just override particular function.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a custom module I believe you can do it through the file requirejs-config.js

Create this file in [YourNamespace]/[YourModule]/view/adminhtml/ with the following code :

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_ProductVideo/js/get-video-information':
            '[YourNamespace]_[YourModule]/js/get-video-information'
    }
}
};
```

Your javascript file should be put in [YourNamespace]/[YourModule]/view/adminhtml/web/js/

Comment: Not working. Help me -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305247/how-to-override-3rd-party-module-requirejs-config-js-film-in-my-custom-module